# Read DSPGROUP_TRUESPEECH encoded wav file in python

Tags: python, scipy

```
import scipy
fs, s = scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename)

unknown wave file format: DSPGROUP_TRUESPEECH. Supported formats PCM, IEEE_FLOAT
```

Is there a way i can read DSPGROUP_TRUESPEECH encoded wav file in python/scipy?!

Comment: You should edit your question and mention what you tried to solve the problem. I've ran a google search with the keywords `DSPGROUP_TRUESPEECH scipy` and came up with the follow result. Does that help: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/io/wavfile.py if not, why not. Please edit your question and add what you have tried and how it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Hi 
I did a basic google search and found the format is not supported by any library i python. The formats supported by scipy is given here https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2f1fc78b3d76fb974be57e1948ac828f7734d6f8/scipy/io/wavfile.py#L542

Comment: Line 307 and following says it all `KNOWN_WAVE_FORMATS = {WAVE_FORMAT.PCM, WAVE_FORMAT.IEEE_FLOAT}` your `DSPGROUP_TRUESPEECH` mentioned in this library but not supported. I guess you need to convert your WAV-Files to PCM before you can read it with scipy. ffmpeg might do it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FFmpeg

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue using @MakMike's suggestion.
Install ffmpeg for converting wavfile encoding

```
ffmpeg -i wavfilename.wav new_wavfilename.wav
```